# Can I automate disabling and enabling a device in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, device-manager, realtek-hd-audio

Let me preface this by saying I am a complete novice with respect to computers.

I have been having issues with the Realtek audio on my Lenovo laptop where it (seemingly at random) shows error messages over media: "Audio Renderer Error, Please Restart Your Computer" (or some similar message).

I found out that instead of restarting my laptop every time I come across this error (which propagates through all media that uses the speakers on my laptop), I can disable and re-enable the Realtek audio device using the Windows Device Manager.

However, this requires a number of steps and takes time. I was wondering if there were a way to accomplish this using a shortcut of sorts? Is there a way to create a command line script or something similar to disable and re-enable a device by just opening a file on my desktop? One click of the mouse is always better than navigating through menus!

I have seen recommendations to use programs like DevCon but all those posts are a number of years old and examples are often with respect to networking issues or on older versions of Windows.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: First try updating your driver and BIOS (Lenovo System Update). The goal should be to fix Audio - not go around it. To restart a service use:  NET RESTART   .. Use net restart /? to see how it works.

Comment: @John Thanks, I have tried the standard troubleshooting tips (windows factory reset, updating drivers, and updating BIOS). I also recently had the system board and speakers replaced (because of an unrelated issue). Problem persists after all that.

Comment: An error like that can be operating system damage and possibly Window User Profile error. It might be best and worth your while to back everything up and reinstall Windows. That will likely clear the error.